# Nested Triggers In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012,  I have devised a system which uses 2 tables and 2 triggers.  Each table has 1 trigger.

Triggers fire AFTER INSERT.

Tables  **A** and **B** , 
Triggers **a** and **b**

When a record is inserted into Table **A**  ,  trigger **a** inserts a record into Table **B**.

When a record is inserted into Table **B** , trigger **b** sends me an email.

The trouble is that trigger **b** only works when I manually insert records into Table **B**.  When trigger **a** does the insert, Trigger **b** does not fire.

I have simplified trigger **b** to a update a third test-table. trigger **b** still does not fire, when trigger **a** does the insert, so it seems unlikely that the email function is to blame.

Comment: when does Trigger A fire? AFTER INSERT or INSTEAD of INSERT?  AFTER Triggers will only cascade if the Server configuration 'nested triggers' is set to 1

Comment: trigger fires AFTER INSERT on TABLE a.  I'll update question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set nested triggers to 1

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```